# How can I access the value of SettingsProperty in a DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

In a WPF applications on can set applications settings in the project configuration.

[image: Settings]

In my app I have a Listview which binds to the settings collection like this:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static properties:Settings.Default}, Path=Properties}" BorderThickness="0">
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate DataType="configuration:SettingsProperty">
              <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding DefaultValue}" />
              </StackPanel>
          </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

This works all fine. My problem is that I can only access the DefaultValue of the SettingsProperty not the value that it is actually set to.

My goal is to be able to display all SettingsProperties and corresponding values without adding a new entry in my xaml file each time I make changes to the settings. I want to add a new SettingsProperty to the settings in VS, recompile the project and my ListView automatically displays name and value of the added property.

Is there a way to access a SettingsProperty current value unsing a binding?

Comment: AFAIK, you can't. either bind to each property instead of `Properties`, or implement a collection to manage settings at run-time

Comment: the reason is you actually have to bind to `Binding Source={x:Static properties:Settings.Default}, Path={Binding Name}}` and it isn't possible to use binding inside path. neither is `Binding {x:Static properties:Settings.Default[{Binding Name}]}`

Comment: What value do you want to display in the ListBox? "Test1" or "Test2"?

Comment: My goal is to display all values dynamically. I want to add a new value to the Settings in VS, recompile and it shows up in my UI.